# How do I find whether a column exists is any other table

Tags: sql

I would like to know how we can find a particular column exists in other tables in SQL. I found the existence in Stored Procedures using the following query

```
SELECT *,ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION,ROUTINE_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%MyColumnName%'
```

How do I check the same for existence in tables?

Comment: @Vijay - the information schema is an Ansi standard and implemented in many different databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information schema views are really useful. I use them for SQL generation all the time.

This query looks at the COLUMNS view and it automatically contains the TABLE and SCHEMA for easy access.

```
SELECT 
   TABLE_SCHEMA,
   TABLE_NAME,

FROM
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
   COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%MyColumnName%'
```

Of course if you're precise then you won't use LIKE rather a  `COLUMN_NAME = 'MyColumnName'` maybe much better.

Comment: Preet Sangha, Works like a charm. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

`if exists (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='' and ')
begin
print 'Column you have specified is exists'
end
else
begin
print 'Column does not exists'
end`

"http://confitech.blogspot.in/2014/05/how-to-find-whether-specific-column.html"